# Search box function for Tool Inventory list

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I have created a template for Tool inventory in excel tab "ESOS" and another tab for searching function tab sheet2.
The Searching is working fine but i won't work if i am not typing the whole word or exactly word for the tool name. 
Example: to look for Drill bits, i have to type in exactly word "Drill bits". i wonder if there is a way for VBA search function to search the whole list even though i am only type in Dri or drill. 
[image]
here is the code.

```
Option Compare Text

Sub searchable()
Dim erow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim count As Integer


lastrow = Sheets("ESOS").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet2.Range("a11:F6000").ClearContents

count = 0

Dim p As Long

p = 11

For x = 2 To lastrow

If Sheets("ESOS").Cells(x, 1) = Sheet2.Range("B3") Then
     Sheet2.Cells(p, 1) = Sheets("ESOS").Cells(x, 1)
     Sheet2.Cells(p, 2) = Sheets("ESOS").Cells(x, 2)
     Sheet2.Cells(p, 3) = Sheets("ESOS").Cells(x, 3)
     Sheet2.Cells(p, 4) = Sheets("ESOS").Cells(x, 4)
     Sheet2.Cells(p, 5) = Sheets("ESOS").Cells(x, 5)
     Sheet2.Cells(p, 6) = Sheets("ESOS").Cells(x, 6)
     p = p + 1
     count = count + 1
End If
Next x

MsgBox " The number of data found for this item code is " & "" & count

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

To get partial matches, change:

```
If Sheets("ESOS").Cells(x, 1) = Sheet2.Range("B3") Then
```

To:

```
If InStr(Sheets("ESOS").Cells(x, 1), Sheet2.Range("B3")) > 0 Then
```

You can also consider making the search case insensitive:

```
If InStr(LCase(Sheets("ESOS").Cells(x, 1)), LCase(Sheet2.Range("B3"))) > 0 Then
```

Also, declaring anything as `Integer` is a bad practice in general, it should be avoided especially if this variable stores row number. If row goes above 32 767, your macro will crash, although in this case it is number of result rows, which should never be this many. Use `Long` instead.

Comment: Thanks Ryszard, your code is working great. I really appreciated it.

Comment: If this solves your problem, please mark it as an answer.